# what it means, how to ckeck response code

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
{
    url:'login.php', 
    DataType: 'json',
    data:{email:user_name, password:pass_word},

    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);

        if (ResponseCode=="200") 
        {
             window.location.href="";
        }
    },
    error: function(error){}
});
```

Comment: Above mentioned data which is an array. To access ResponceCode you will use array index like array[0].ResponceCode. Here array contain above mentioned data.

Comment: can you elaborate your requirements

Comment: in above ajax code it give json array. i want to check response code and i want to redirect to corresponding page

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your problem.

```
if (data[0].ResponseCode=="200") 
    {
         window.location.href="";
    }
```

Comment: as i want to convert array to object?

Comment: Share format of response which you send back from login.php. Also console.log(data); log

Comment: [{"pk_int_login_id":"1","vchr_first_name":"Haris","vchr_last_name":"Np","vchr_prof_pic":"http:\/\/files.baabtra.com\/profile_pic\/haris.png","ResponseCode":"200","Msg":"Success"}]

Comment: use this if (data[0].ResponseCode=="200")

Comment: Can you share full request code.  and also library version which you are using. is it jQuery?